# SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Rows > 0

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7, this query runs fine:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Rows > 0
```

In MySQL 8.022, it produces the following fault:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rows > 0' at line 1
```

It seems there's no issue with querying on other status columns:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Data_length > 0 
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Avg_row_length > 0
```

... and so on.

Is this a known issue with this version of MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R says;

```
ROWS (R); became reserved in 8.0.2
```

Since `Rows` now is a reserved keyword, it needs to be quoted to use in that way;

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Rows` > 0
```

Comment: Confirmed, this is the solution. Thank you @joachim-isaksson